# codeigniter: unable to get the accurate time for today's

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have to insert current date & time  into my database table in order to track   users "when was their last visits"

Currently i am in India. In My windows system, its showing `5/13/2013 5:58 Pm` 
But the below code is showing me the today data & time as `2013-05-13 13:02:28` . Why time is not accurate.

**I want to make the timing accurate for all users around the world.**

I used the below code . Please help me to find this answer.

```
   $this->load->database();
   $this->load->helper('date');   
   $datestring = "%Y-%m-%d: %d:%h:%i";

   $time = time(); 
   $today=mdate($datestring, $time);

   echo($today);//showing not accurate time, as i explained it above
```

If my question is not clear, then please comment below, i wil try to explain you in diffrent ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's giving you a `UTC` time , while Indian Timezone is `UTC + 5.30`. So you need to set your timezone to `Asia/Calcutta` in your root index or config file.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
```

Also you need to change your $dateString.

```
$datestring = "%Y-%m-%d: %H:%i:%s";
```

Comment: Thank You, but again if i change this, then the users who are not from asia/Calcutta , then for them it will show wrong time? I want to show to make this in such a way that it should give correct time for all users around the world? What you suggest?

Comment: @Ashutosh - Than just change the timezone on fly.

Comment: Did you mean i have to change the timezone based on users ip address dynamically whenever the do any activities?  . And i will store the timezone name in my db  ?

Comment: In a way. [Read More](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone).

Comment: Sorry, i tried your above code `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");` and i kept it in my root index.php but also the same problem. And also i tested it in my config.php  but also same problem

Comment: Check [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JWzWjt). Your `$dateString` is incorrect.

Comment: I am trying to implement this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone/1809974#1809974 to accoplish my need. But i am confuse, how can i put this in my config.php file , and call `-new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60;` this one. Even the answer is not in simple. Please help me to do this.

Comment: It's probably easiest to store the time as UTC and convert it on output. You can use CI's `local_to_gmt` and `gmt_to_local` to do the conversion. Or you can use PHP's `DateTime`/`DateTimezone` classes.

Comment: @mcrumley  so did you mean, first i set `date_default_timezone_set("UTC");` in my config.php and wherever i am inserting date there i will use this function `gmt_to_local`?

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set` doesn't really matter, but it should be set to something reasonable (the timezone your server is set to). `gmt_to_local` takes an argument that is the user's timezone. That will need to be set per user and stored in their profile.